# Own Encoding System with str_replace

Tags: php

I was thinking about creating a own encode system with just using str_replace.
But is this even possible or should I use other methods?

I had this

```
$provided_data = $_POST["provided_data"];

$pd2 = str_replace("a", "[...]", $provided_data);
$pd3 = str_replace("b", "[...]", $pd2);
$pd4 = str_replace("c", "[...]", $pd3);
[shortend]
$pd28 = str_replace(" ", "[...]", $pd27);

$encrypted_data = $pd28;
```

The result should show the encrypted data. But when I try it, it doesn't return me anything.

Comment: What's the input you gave?

Comment: I typed "hello" and got no output. @WhatIf

Comment: Did you checked $provided_data has the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the input is passed correctly. The below code prints "[...][...][...][...][...]".

```
<?php
$provided_data = 'hello';

$pd2 = str_replace("h", "[...]", $provided_data);
$pd3 = str_replace("e", "[...]", $pd2);
$pd4 = str_replace("l", "[...]", $pd3);
$pd28 = str_replace("o", "[...]", $pd4);

echo $pd28; //prints "[...][...][...][...][...]"

?>
```

Online PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me.
I was pretty sure, my code was also correct, but I saw, it wasn't.

Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: My pleasure anyway. 